# Calling a super method in Java

Tags: java

```
Customer.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
super.display();
      ^
symbol: method display()

1 error
```

This what is happening when I compile my program. How do I display the objects data in the `Customer` subclass?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String number;

    //No Argument constructor//
    public Person() {
        name = "";
        address = "";
        number = "";
    }

    //Explicit value constructor//
    public Person(String num, String nam, String add) {
        number = num;
        name = nam;
        address = add;
    }

    //Accessor method//
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    //Mutator method//
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getTelephoneNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + "\n" + address + "\n" + number;
    }
}
```

The subclass:

```
public class Customer extends Person {

    public Customer(String num, String nam, String add) {
        super(num, nam, add);
    }

    public boolean checkResponse(char response) {
        if (response == 'Y') {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void display() {
        super.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: `super.display();` is the problem. Its not there in superclass.

Comment: @Sandhu:  Please don't add more content to the question that you're editing.  It muddles the intent of the actual code, and could provide red herrings for others to solve.

Comment: @Makoto I just formatted the code. That's all. I didn't add anything more. Please recheck my edit in edit history

Comment: @Sandhu:  That `System.out.println` came out of nowhere.  Are you sure you only reformatted the code?

Comment: @Makoto It was there in his first question

Comment: ohh ok I had not noticed

Answer (score 3):

In order for `super.display()` to work, you require a method called `display()` in your parent class.

Since you have no such method, Java will not allow the code you have to compile.

Since it seems you're trying to show useful information about the object when it's printed, why not override `toString()` again?  The caveat here is that you don't have any more meaningful information to show about it being a `Customer` over it being a `Person` (there's no `Customer`-specific fields, so the inheritance relationship is moot).

You may want to consider adding more info to differentiate a `Customer` from a `Person`, *then* override `toString()`.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because there is no `display()` method in the `Person` class. So you cant invoke a non existing method using `super.display()`

So change the `display()` method in `Customer` to

```
   public void display() {
        System.out.println(super.toString());
   }
```

Comment: so how do I override the toString method in my Customer Class

Comment: Thank you it compile I just omitted the   **System.out.println("Customer telephone number:" + number);**

Answer (score 0):

As the error is trying to tell you, `super.display()` doesn't exist.

Comment: how do I make it relevant in other words how do I override the tostring method

Answer (score 0):

You don't have display() function defined in parent class(Pesron);

Answer (score 0):

You can simply access the number, name or address directly. Modify the display() method, remove super.display() like below.

```
public void display()
{
  System.out.println("Customer telephone number:" + number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Super` keyword in java is related to parent class and `Super.display()` means you are calling the display method of the parent class.Your parent class is person as you are extending it `public class Customer extends Person {`

But there is no `display()` in person hence your are getting compilation error